# How to terminate reading from text file when file is empty

Tags: c#

When I run my program and there is data in my text file it works as I intended. However, the program crashes if the text file is empty. Therefore, I was wondering how I remedy this issue.

Here is my code for reading from text file:

```
//This method reads the order data from a text file and assigns the values to each object's variables
    void Read_Order_Data()
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream("i:\\OrderData.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fs);

        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            string line = reader.ReadLine();
            string[] fields = line.Split('#');
            Order[Number_Of_Orders].Order_Number = fields[0];
            Order[Number_Of_Orders].Type_Of_Bean = fields[1];
            Order[Number_Of_Orders].Quantity_Of_Order = fields[2];
            Order[Number_Of_Orders].Date_Of_Purchase = fields[3];
            Number_Of_Orders++;
        }//end of while statement
        reader.Close();
    }//end of Read_Order_Data()
```

If the text file is empty my program stops on this line:

```
Order[Number_Of_Orders].Type_Of_Bean = fields[1];
```

When it stops it says Type_Of_Bean is null.

Thanks for any assistance you can offer.

Answer (score 5):

Change your `while` loop a bit:

```
string line;
while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    string[] fields = line.Split('#');
    ... 
}
```

`line` will be `null` if the end of the input stream has been reached.

A simpler option may be to use `Peek()`. I modified the [MSDN's example for `StreamReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.io.streamreader.readline%28v=vs.90%29) a tiny bit:

```
string line;
while (reader.Peek() >= 0) 
{
    line = reader.ReadLine();
    ...
}
```

`Peek()` will return `-1` if there are no characters to be read (empty file).

And as others have suggested, make sure your split string array result has the number of fields you plan on indexing. If it doesn't, it might suggest a problem with the file you're reading.

Comment: Sorry for delay in posting. That worked perfectly mate. Thanks for taking the time to help me.

Comment: @user3478049: My pleasure. I see you're new; don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it provided a solid solution. Welcome to [so]!

Answer (score 0):

Replace This:

```
string[] fields = line.Split('#');
```

With This:

```
string[] fields = line.Split(new []{'#'},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add checking for length of fields in your code, like this:

```
        ...
        string[] fields = line.Split(new[] {'#'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        if (fields.Length < 4) break;
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check if field have the correct length

```
   void Read_Order_Data()
    {
       FileStream fs = new FileStream("i:\\OrderData.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
       StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fs);

    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        string line = reader.ReadLine();
        string[] fields = line.Split('#');
        if (fields.length == 4){
           Order[Number_Of_Orders].Order_Number = fields[0];
           Order[Number_Of_Orders].Type_Of_Bean = fields[1];
           Order[Number_Of_Orders].Quantity_Of_Order = fields[2];
           Order[Number_Of_Orders].Date_Of_Purchase = fields[3];
           Number_Of_Orders++;
        }
    }//end of while statement
    reader.Close();
}//end of Read_Order_Data()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("File");
foreach (var line in lines)
{
     string[] fields = line.Split('#');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you file is empty, then the following line

```
string[] fields = line.Split('#');
```

will give you a string array with only one element (empty string).

Which means that when trying to access the second element (`fields[1]`), your code will raise an exception.

Short story: you should check the size of the fields array before accessing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can enumerate a line at a time without having to buffer the entire contents like so:

```
foreach (string line in File.ReadLines("i:\\OrderData.txt"))
{
    string[] fields = line.Split('#');

    if (fields.Length < 4) // You might also need to add this.
        continue;

    ...
```

If the file is empty, it will not even enter the body of the loop. It also does not make a copy of the entire file in memory - only one line is buffered in memory at once.